# Is it possible for two MCUs to monitor the same analog voltage signal?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, analog, adc, voltage-measurement

I was thinking about tying two separate microcontroller inputs together so that they would be on the same node and monitoring the same voltage signal. Both basically doing the same thing (analog to digital conversion of the same node) and was wondering if that is a common thing to do for designs or if there are problems that may arise that I am not aware of.

Comment: As long as the output impedance is low and the input impedance is high. If not, buffer.

Comment: Possible as said above, but why?

Comment: Both MCU's have separate tasks based on this signal. Just spreading the work around and keeping the tasks separate helps.

Comment: What will happen if their readings are significantly different? If nothing bad, then it is probably fine, if not, then better to have a single source of the reading being distributed digitally between the MCUs.

Comment: Yes it is possible but the problems depend on what you expect from the circuit. If one of the MCUs is unpowered, it will likely load down the signal voltae so that the other MCU will measure it incorrectly. Please define the problem better.

Answer (score 0):

In principle there is no issue provided the source can drive both inputs without excessive error.

There are not a lot of valid reasons to do this in a new design (as opposed to something being tacked onto an existing setup) so it's probably not that common.

One potential reason would be for redundancy, and if that is the justification you have to be very careful that a failure in one MCU cannot affect the other.